# Traversing a nested FormArray in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I am trying to traverse through a nested FormArray to keep track of a set of questions, each given their own 'FormControl'. I have created a FormArray called 'groups' as such. The hierarchy goes Groups[Questions[Answers]]

```
constructor(private surveyService: SurveyService, @Inject(FormBuilder) private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.survey = <Survey>SURVEYS[0];

    this.reactiveForm = fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      groups: fb.array(this.getGroups())
    });

}

getGroups() : AbstractControl[] {
    return Array.apply(null,
      Array(this.survey.groups.length)).map((x, index) => new FormArray(this.getQuestions(index)))
  }

getQuestions(index) : AbstractControl[] {
    return Array.apply(null,
      Array(this.survey.groups[index].questions.length)).map(x => new FormControl(x, Validators.required));
  }
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<form [formGroup]="reactiveForm">
  <div formArrayName="groups">
    <div *ngFor="let group of survey.groups; index as groupIndex" [formArrayName]=groupIndex>
      <h1>{{group.groupName}}</h1>
      <div *ngFor="let question of group.questions; index as questionIndex" [formArrayName]=questionIndex>
        <h2>{{question.question}}</h2>
        <label *ngFor="let answer of question.responses ; index as answerIndex">
          <input type="radio" [value]=answerIndex [formControlName]=questionIndex>{{answer}}
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I figure it to work as such: the first ngFor pulls the array of Questions, the second ngFor pulls the array of answers, and then the final ngFor uses [formControlName] in order to bind each question to the same Control, giving it a unique answer. However, the error I get is this:

```
Error: Cannot find control with path: 'groups -> 0 -> 0 -> 0'
```

If Groups[0] is an array and Groups[0][0] is also an array, why does the [0] of that suddenly not exist anymore? How should one go about traversing a FormArray like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you have created:

[image]

Now look at your template:

```
<form [formGroup]="reactiveForm">
  <div formArrayName="groups">
    <div ... [formArrayName]=groupIndex>
      ...
      <div ... [formArrayName]=questionIndex>
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
             Do you see such FormArray in your FormGroup? I don't
        <...
        <label *ngFor="let answer of question.responses ; index as answerIndex">
          <input ...[formControlName]=questionIndex>...
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

As you can see you Angular can't find FormControl by path `groups -> 0 -> 0 -> 0` because it should be `groups -> 0 -> 0`

So if you will remove redundant `[formArrayName]=questionIndex` directive then it should work.

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/EfRA6s4yhtzofnVblZ8s)**

*Tip:* use `<pre>{{reactiveForm.value | json}}</pre>` to test `FormGroup` structure

Answer (score 0):

For demo I used simple structure:

```
export class Group {
  title: string;
  questions: Question[] = [];

}

export class Question {
  title: string;
  answers: Answer[] = [];    
}

export class Answer {
  id: number;
  title: string;
}
```

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-deep-phnik3)